# How to get the minimum value of an array, based on comparing more than one block using min_by?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Given this example array of numbers:

```
sizes = [35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60]
```

And this required size to fit:

```
fit_this = 30
```

I want to find the minimum size based on these given blocks:

```
sizes.min_by { |size| (size - fit_this).abs }   #=> 35
sizes.min_by { |size| (size - fit_this*2).abs } #=> 60
```

The sizes are widths, and I'm trying to put as many `fit_this` items into the width with the least amount of wasted space, so the `fit_this` number can be doubled up if it's a better fit.

Is it possible to do this with `min_by`? If not, what's the best way to do it in Ruby?

Comment: sorry i don't really understand your mean, could you gimme the expected result here?

Comment: The expected result is 60.

Comment: @massaskillz you might want to explain, *why* 60 is the better fit. I don't think it's obvious.

Comment: @Stefan, thanks for the suggestion. I edited the question.

Comment: Seems like you could just use `sizes.min_by { |size| size % fit_this }`

Comment: @Stefan ah yes, this one is much cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's examine the intermediate arrays by replacing `min_by` with `map`:

```
sizes.map { |size| (size - fit_this).abs }
#=> [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]

sizes.map { |size| (size - fit_this*2).abs }
#=> [25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0]
```

We can combine both calculations by returning element-wise arrays:

```
sizes.map { |size| [(size - fit_this).abs, (size - fit_this*2).abs] }
#=> [[5, 25], [10, 20], [15, 15], [20, 10], [25, 5], [30, 0]]
```

And use `min` to fetch the smaller number of each pair:

```
sizes.map { |size| [(size - fit_this).abs, (size - fit_this*2).abs].min }
#=> [5, 10, 15, 10, 5, 0]
```

Applied to `min_by`:

```
sizes.min_by { |size| [(size - fit_this).abs, (size - fit_this*2).abs].min }
#=> 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can do that.

The basic idea is we want to try for two cases for all sizes and choose what is the best fit:

```
sizes.min_by { |size| [(size - fit_this).abs, (size - fit_this * 2).abs].min }
```